# Add Index to postgreSQL query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query result looks like this:

```
| A | B |
|-------|
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 9 |
```

Now I want to increase column A by the index of the result table, so the result would become like this:

```
| A | B |
|-------|
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 9 |
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by index?

Comment: Why do you want to start from 2?  Do you always want to start from 2 or because b starts from 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `row_number()`

```
select (row_number() over (order by a) + 1) as A, b
from table t;
```

Comment: There is no need to put an expression between parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
SELECT 
    (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY A) + A) AS columnAIndex, 
     columnB
FROM ...
```

I don't have a PostgreSQL client installed here, therefore, i don't tested this query.